# When Running a report, how do I exclude 12:00:00.000 when searching a datetime range

Tags: sql, datetime, getdate

I am trying to run a report to return everything with a date of "tomorrow" but I want to include from 12:01:00.000 to 11:59:00.000 in that date.  i can only return from current datetime and forward 24 hours.

```
AND e.event_date >= getdate()+2
AND e.event_date < getdate()+3
```

How do I write this?

Comment: What language are you using to query the report data?

Comment: It is a program written by our vendor but we can run sql reports from it.  I'm not the programmer, just the person who runs the reports.  Sorry I can't help with that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are creating your reports via T-SQL, this will do the trick:

```sql
AND e.event_date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
AND e.event_date < DATEADD(DAY, 2, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

This will filter all entries with event_date of tomorrow.

You cannot get the current date directly in SQL, but you can convert the current DateTime to a Date object which will strip off the information about time.

If you want to exclude 12:00:00.000 (Why would you?), just modify your comparer:

```sql
AND e.event_date > DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: I am trying to run a report to return times for the date, but if a user doesn't put in a time, i want to exclude that time.  It is to extract information for automated appointment reminders.

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Comment: I did but it doesn't remove the midnight time of 00:00:00.000

Comment: Did you try the secon suggestion? `AND e.event_date > DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))` Note the removed equals sign. Otherwise you can add one more minute: `AND e.event_date > DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))`

Comment: will try that.  had to leave work for something.  thanks.

Comment: I tried that this morning Sebastian and the one without the minute worked perfectly.  I tested with time changes and it works.  Thank you so much for your help, I had driven myself crazy on that one.

Comment: Glad I could help. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)